# PyQt5 - Failed to load platform plugin "windows". Available platforms are: windows, minimal

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

When I try to run any PyQt5 program from Eclipse, I got this error.

> Failed to load platform plugin "windows". Available platforms are: windows, minimal

I've never encountered this problem with PyQt4 but with the new version.

I'm not able to run a program. From other questions here I know it happens with Qt C++ development and the solution is to copy some Qt dll files to executable program directory.

Do I need to do the same in Python development (PyQt5) too? Add those files to the directory, where my *.py files reside? Shouldn't this be managed by PyQt5 installation?

Thank you

Answer (score 11):

I encountered this issue with PyQt5 5.0.2, Windows 8, Python 3.3.2; slightly different error message:

`Failed to load platform plugin "windows". Available platforms are:`

Set the following environment variable and then run the application.

`$env:QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH="C:\Python33\Lib\site-packages\PyQt5\plugins\platforms"`

Comment: Awesome, how did you found this variable?

Comment: You should explain how to set that env variable.

Answer (score 7):

Copy `C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\PyQt5\libEGL.dll` to the same directory as your .exe.

Source: http://bird1110.blogspot.com/2014/04/python-33-pyqt5-and-cxfreeze-exe-on-64.html

Answer (score 5):

i had a similar problem when compiling my code with `cx_freeze`.

Copying the folder **platforms** from python installation directory into my built folder solved the problem. the "platforms" folder contains qminimal.dll

Comment: Thanks for your hint! I'm using cx_freeze to package my pyqt5 executable file. I find I could add 'include_files' in option, which includes the platforms folder. Then it could work.

Answer (score 4):

Another solution which works for me; Windows 7; PyQt5, Python 3.4 64bit:

```
pyqt = os.path.dirname(PyQt5.__file__)
QApplication.addLibraryPath(os.path.join(pyqt, "plugins"))
```

You can also set an environment variable `QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH` with the path to the `plugins` directory.

```
os.environ['QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH'] = qt_platform_plugins_path
```

This also works very well with PyInstaller!

Comment: This only works if you 'import PyQt5' first
https://github.com/pyqt/python-qt5/issues/2

Comment: Ofcourse that before calling `PyQt`, it must be imported.

Answer (score 1):

I found the file: qwindows.dll needed to be included to allow my .exe file to run independently without getting the error.  To do so, add the qwindows.dll path to your data files list:

```
setup(windows=[YOURSCRIPT.py]
, data_files = [('.','DRIVE:\PythonPath\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\plugings\platforms\qwindows.dll')])
```

The reason you would do this and now set your environment path is that your program will run on any machine if the qwindows.dll file is held in the same package.  If you only set the environment variable, the program will only successfully run on a computer with PyQt installed.

Answer (score 1):

I like uetoyo's answer, but Anaconda has moved the directory.  This works for me Python 3.5.2 Anaconda 4.2.0 on Windows 7.

```
import os
if os.name == "nt":  # if windows
    import PyQt5
    pyqt_plugins = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(PyQt5.__file__),
                                "..", "..", "..", "Library", "plugins")
    QApplication.addLibraryPath(pyqt_plugins)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me while using the Anaconda Python 3.6 distribution:

1. I installed PyQt5 using `pip install pyqt5`. What this does is it creates a `Qt/Plugins`plugins directory in the `../Anaconda3/Lib/site-packages/PyQt5` path.
2. Following Roger Allen and uetoyo, I added:

```py
if os.name == "nt":  # if windows
    from PyQt5 import __file__
    pyqt_plugins = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "Qt", "plugins")
    QApplication.addLibraryPath(pyqt_plugins)
    os.environ['QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH'] = pyqt_plugins
```

to my script. It works with pyinstaller as well.

Answer (score 0):

if you use PySide2 you can check with this

```
import os
if os.name == 'nt':
    import PySide2
    pyqt = os.path.dirname(PySide2.__file__)
    QApplication.addLibraryPath(os.path.join(pyqt, "plugins"))
```