# PyQt with PyDev - failed to load platform

Tags: python, windows, pyqt, pyqt4, pydev

I'm trying to learn PyQt via Pydev / Eclipse.

I've installed Python 3.3, and PyQt 4.4 (PyQt4-4.10.3-gpl-Py3.3-Qt5.1.0-x32), on Windows 7 32-bit. I've followed the installation procedure from PyDev site to the letter and vanilla Python applications work fine. I've then written the simplest application which uses PyQt4 (a Hello World QWidget) but at the QApplication line I get the following:

```
Failed to load platform plugin "windows". Available platforms are: 
minimal
windows
```

So it can't load "windows" even though it is apparently available?

Code runs fine in IDLE btw, the Hello World widget appears as expected and everything's dandy. I've also tried the suggestion from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17695027/pyqt5-failed-to-load-platform-plugin-windows-available-platforms-are-windo), i.e. to set the QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH env. variable, but this only changes the above error to this one:

```
Failed to load platform plugin "windows". Available platforms are: 
minimal (from C:\Python33\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\plugins\platforms)
windows (from C:\Python33\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\plugins\platforms)
minimal
```

Thanks for any insight about is, cause I'm kinda stumped. Cheers!

Branko

Comment: A web-search on the error message gets lots of hits, with a variety of different solutions (most seem to involve copying various dll's to certain plugin directories). I would suggest you try a few of them out and report back if nothing works.

Comment: Yes, but most of those are for the scenarios where the "available platforms" list is empty, and they involve copying the "qwindows.dll" file in the platforms directory. However, as you can see, windows platform does get detected on my system, and still it complains it cannot load it.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to have been a version-related issue between PyDev, PyQt 4.4 and Qt5.1.

After installing the PyQt5 variant:

**PyQt5-5.1.1-gpl-Py3.3-Qt5.1.1-x32.exe**

and switching to PyQt5 everything works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I've also run into this exact problem because I had installed Python/PyQt in a non-default directory.  Adding "\python34\Lib\site-packages\PyQt5" to the PATH environment variable before starting Eclipse did the trick for me.