# App failed to start because it could not find Qt platform plugin "Windows" in ""

Tags: windows, anaconda, pyqt5, python-3.6

I have been bogging my mind on this one for a few days with various versions of python and freeze utilities. 
Python 3.6, PyQt5 
I created a script, and am trying to make a standalone .exe 
However, when running pyinstaller, I get the result I have posted below. I am currently using an Anaconda distribution, so I am not sure if this has anything to do with it. How do I resolve this issue?

I have tried to fix it for several days using different python and pyqt versions, but the short story is that some of the libraries I am using come into conflict in other versions. I am posting this again because nothing else has really worked, and I am on my last straws.

Thanks in advance.
Error Window:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

From this page:
[PyQt5 - Failed to load platform plugin "windows". Available platforms are: windows, minimal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17695027/pyqt5-failed-to-load-platform-plugin-windows-available-platforms-are-windo)
this answer solved my problem.
Copying the folder platforms from python installation directory into my built folder solved the problem. the "platforms" folder contains qminimal.dll.
Maybe it helps you too!

Comment: Thank you!! It's really annoying that it doesn't include it within the --onefile! I added the .dll within .spec, and it still doesn't open without the folder..

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to install Anaconda in a folder that does not use non-ascii characters?

Also, you say you have done `conda update --all`, but your Qt version states 5.6.0. Last week we released version 5.6.2, so `conda update --all` should have got that version for you.

Perhaps try `conda update qt` and see that it installs 5.6.2?