# Trying to create 1 executable from Pycharm project

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm

How can I create 1 executable file from my Pycharm project. I need every file listed in the screenshot below to be included. I have downloaded cv_freeze, py2exe , and pyinstaller. I have tried to use pyinstaller but it gives me an error. It tells me that: error: the following arguments are required: scriptname. How can I include all files shown below under the 1 executable?

When i do include a script say InformationWindow.py, it does create the executable but it does not run when i click the executable. It gives me an error stating that "this application failed to start because it could not find the qt platform plugin windows"

[image]

Comment: Do you have a single "main" python file that you use to run your program? If so, have you tried creating the executable using the following: `pyinstaller MainGuiWindow.py` (or whatever your main file is)? Check the documents for instructions for PyInstaller usage: http://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html

Comment: the InformationWindow.py file is the main file technically speaking because it it written in such a way that when I press an option, MainGuiWindow.py opens. I have created an executable out of InformationWindow.py but it will not run. It keeps giving me an error: This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "windows". Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Comment: Its ok, I figured it out. I just copied the platforms folder into the same directory as the executable file just like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17695027/pyqt5-failed-to-load-platform-plugin-windows-available-platforms-are-windo