# Qt platform plugin issue Rstudio

Tags: python, r, qt, rstudio, reticulate

I am trying to do a seaborn heatmap plot via RStudio.

I use`reticulate` package in R.

Below is my code:

```
library(reticulate)
use_condaenv("python36", conda = "auto", required = FALSE)
os <- import("os")
os$listdir(".")
py_available()


sns <- import('seaborn')
plt <- import('matplotlib.pyplot')
pd <- import('pandas')


dat <- AirPassengers
# convert time series to data frame
dat <- data.frame(matrix(dat, ncol=frequency(dat), dimnames=dimnames(.preformat.ts(dat)) ))
dat
sns$heatmap(r_to_py(dat), fmt = "g", cmap = "viridis")
plt$show()
```

However, I receive the following error and my R session gets aborted when it reaches the seaborn heatmap line. What should I do to fix this error?

[image: Qt error]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem with RStudio daily build 1.2.114 and a  Anaconda Python 3.7 environment where I had PyTorch and `matplotlib` installed.

I followed the instructions by @Sheperd, with the following changes, pointing to the environment where you have `matplotlib` installed; in my case `pytorch37`:

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

import os
os.environ['QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH'] = 'C:/Users/user_name/Anaconda3/envs/pytorch37/Library/plugins/platforms'

t = np.arange(0.0, 2.0, 0.01)
s = 1 + np.sin(2 * np.pi * t)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(t, s)

ax.set(xlabel='time (s)', ylabel='voltage (mV)',
       title='About as simple as it gets, folks')
ax.grid()

plt.show()
```

Now, `PyQt` is found and **RStudio** doesn't crash anymore.

Comment: I'm also working on Windows and this solved the issue so commenting and upvoting as this was the best answer I found.

Answer (score 4):

this seems like a duplicate question. I am using RStudio-1.2.679 with R-3.4.4 to write and edit Python code. I was having the exact same problem, I tried many solutions but nothing seemed to work. Finally I found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50711837/5350172) -I take absolutely no credit for it. This is, at the top of your Python code (file with extension .py) where you import libraries include:

```
import os
os.environ['QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH'] = 'C:/Users/myusername/AppData/Local/Continuum/Anaconda3/Library/plugins/platforms'
```

Notice that is how the path looks like in my PC, it may look different in yours.

Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50711837/5350172) example:

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import os
os.environ['QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH'] = 'C:/Users/myusername/AppData/Local/Continuum/Anaconda3/Library/plugins/platforms'

t = np.arange(0.0, 2.0, 0.01)
s = 1 + np.sin(2 * np.pi * t)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(t, s)

ax.set(xlabel='time (s)', ylabel='voltage (mV)',
       title='About as simple as it gets, folks')
ax.grid()

plt.show()
```

This shows the plot in the "Plots" panel in RStudio. Best wishes!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a script to run directly in R, for Anaconda users:

```
library(reticulate)

use_condaenv(condaenv = "your conda env", required = T)

py_run_string('import os')
py_run_string("os.environ['QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH'] = '/path/to/Anaconda3/Library/plugins/platforms'")

np = import("numpy",delay_load = T)
plt = import("matplotlib.pyplot",delay_load = T)

t = np$arange(0.01, 10.0, 0.01)

data1 = np$exp(t)
data2 = np$sin(2 * np$pi * t)

#These last lines must be run together:

fig = plt$figure(figsize=c(14,8))
plt$plot(1:10,1:10)
plt$show()
```

Enjoy!!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not using Anaconda but using miniconda and reticulate for R-studio

So I used

```
import os

os.environ['QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH'] = 'C:\Users\<user-name>\AppData\Local\r-miniconda\envs\r-reticulate\Library\plugins\platforms'`
```

It worked, Thank you @Shepherd and @F0nzie

Comment: Please do not repeat an already given answer, just upvote it (once you have enough reputation)