# Unable to Knit To PDF the R-notebook containing Python code

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown, knitr, reticulate

I am **KNIT TO PDF** this R-notebook containing the following Python code:

[image]

```
import matplotlib
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

t = np.arange(0.0, 2.0, 0.01)
s = 1 + np.sin(2*np.pi*t)
plt.plot(t, s)
plt.xlabel('time (s)')
plt.ylabel('voltage (mV)')
plt.grid(True)
plt.savefig("test.png")
plt.show()
```

When I choose Knit To PDF, this error appears:

> This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "windows" in "". Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.
>
> [image]

On the other hand, when choosing to **Knit To PDF** a R-notebook that contains only R code, everything works fine.

Could you please help me resolve this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer for my question at https://stackoverflow.com/a/50711837/7357673. I posted it here to close this question and for future visitors.