# Problem using knitter with reticulate package in rstudio with matplotlib

Tags: r, knitr, reticulate

To elaborate on the title,

I am using rstudio making an rmarkdown file that contains both r and python code. My configuration is below:

```
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 18363)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United Kingdom.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United Kingdom.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United Kingdom.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                            LC_TIME=English_United Kingdom.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.4.6         rstudioapi_0.11      knitr_1.28           magrittr_1.5         rappdirs_0.3.1       tidyselect_1.0.0    
 [7] munsell_0.5.0        lattice_0.20-38      colorspace_1.4-1     R6_2.4.1             rlang_0.4.5          dplyr_0.8.5         
[13] tools_3.6.3          grid_3.6.3           gtable_0.3.0         xfun_0.12            htmltools_0.4.0      yaml_2.2.1          
[19] assertthat_0.2.1     digest_0.6.25        tibble_2.1.3         lifecycle_0.2.0      crayon_1.3.4         Matrix_1.2-18       
[25] purrr_0.3.3          ggplot2_3.3.0        rsconnect_0.8.16     glue_1.3.2           evaluate_0.14        rmarkdown_2.1       
[31] compiler_3.6.3       pillar_1.4.3         scales_1.1.0         jsonlite_1.6.1       reticulate_1.15-9000 pkgconfig_2.0.3
```

The python chunk I try running is:

```
import scipy as sp
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


df = pd.read_csv("D:/03 PhD Edinburgh related/OneDrive/OneDrive - University of Edinburgh/00 PhD/000 PhD Data/01 Project I Chr Hansen/20200421_analysis_pp16013/20200420_pp16013_analysis.csv")

plt.scatter(df['OD'].values, df['osmolarity.mOSM'].values,
            c=df['hydrophobicity'].values,cmap='magma')
plt.xlabel('OD')
plt.ylabel('osmolarity')
plt.title('osmolarity as function of OD and Hydrophobicity')

cbar = plt.colorbar()
cbar.set_label('Hydrophobicity', rotation=270)

plt.show()
```

I can run the python chunk fine in rStudio and display the graph as expect.

When I try using knitter to make the document it gets to the python chunk and gives the error:

```
"This application failed to start because it could not find or load 
the Qt platform plugin "windows" in "", 
reinstalling the application may fix this problem."
```

This is specifically related to the part using matplotlib. I can create and display the Pandas data frame.

I have tried installing the latest version of reticulate of github.

Thank you for any help in advance.

Comment: Did you try to google this error message? I found [this](https://forum.qt.io/topic/90293/could-not-find-or-load-the-qt-platform-plugin-windows-in)

Comment: Yes, google revealed that it is most likely related to the reticulate package. I followed instructions to update to the most recent version by directly installing the package from github.

Comment: But the link I provided talks about the PATH to modify when this error occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to find the issue in another stack overflow answer this is a duplicate.

For answer please look here.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/50711837/11076186

I basically just save my python plot and then load the saved python plot in r.

Answer (score 1):

In my rmarkdown file, it works fine after setting the plugin path of the conda environment being used. You can add the below r code chunk before using matplotlib for python code chunk.

```
library(reticulate)
py_run_string("import os as os")
py_run_string("os.environ['QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH'] = 'C:/Users/[UserID]/Anaconda3/envs/[EnvironmentName]/Library/plugins/platforms'")
```

Comment: Hi thanks I feel like this is going in the right direction.

I tried using my installation of python:
    C:/Users/mzurb/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38-32/python.exe

This did not work can you tell me what this platforms folder is as I do not have anaconda3?

Comment: In my platforms folder, I can find "qwindows.dll" file. Maybe, you can try locating the file around your installation folder, and point to the folder containing the file if you could find one?