# R : install matplotlib in the new Rstudio preview version

Tags: python, r, reticulate

I loaded the *reticulate* package, if it matters.

In a **python script in R**, the below commands work.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
```

But this one doesn't

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

The console says : ModuleNotFoundError: no module named 'matplotlib'

In R's terminal I'm trying to do *pip install matplotlib* , but I get the error 'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: Here's another [possible solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76580675/6937482).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you need to use the [py_install](https://rstudio.github.io/reticulate/reference/py_install.html) function provided in the `reticulate` package.

It should work: `py_install(packages = "matplotlib")`

In case you are using an virtual environment, try the [virtualenv_install](https://rstudio.github.io/reticulate/reference/virtualenv-tools.html) function.

Comment: great thanks! but i'm getting an error to install 'sklearn.
PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:'
To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

   https://anaconda.org

Comment: I don't know why this is happening. I just tried on a new Rstudio cloud project and it worked fine. Perhaps you should ask a new question, or see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48493505/packagesnotfounderror-the-following-packages-are-not-available-from-current-cha